# Python ini parser

Tags: python, file, ini, configparser

Is there a parser which reads and stores the types of data to write?
File format must to produce a readable.
Shelve does not offer.

Comment: [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html)

Comment: Does ConfigParser not do what you want?

Comment: I need support automatic type detection. ConfigParser reads everything as a string.

Comment: Correction - ConfigParser allows you to read in values of different datatypes, but you need to know the type of each as you read it.

Comment: Do you know what types the config items should be, or are you trying to read arbitrary ini files?

Comment: I know that is in the ini file, but it is too big for me to convert it manually.

Comment: `configobj` is much simpler to use than `configparser`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ConfigParser` class to read configuration files in the ini file format:

http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#examples

The ini file format does not store the datatype of the values stored (you need to know them as you read the data back).  You could overcome this limitation by encoding your values in json format:

```
import simplejson
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('example.cfg')

value = 123
#or value = True
#or value = 'Test'

#Write any data to 'Section1->Foo' in the file:
parser.set('Section1', 'foo', simplejson.dumps(value))

#Now you can close the parser and start again...

#Retrieve the value from the file:
out_value = simplejson.loads(parser.get('Section1', 'foo'))

#It will match the input in both datatype and value:
value === out_value
```

Being json, the format of the stored value is human readable.

Comment: I need a parser that automatically detects when reading the record type.

Comment: Then store strings in json format, so that you can read types too?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function

```
def getvalue(parser, section, option):
    try:
        return parser.getint(section, option)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return parser.getfloat(section, option)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return parser.getbool(section, option)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return parser.get(section, option)
```

Comment: If you store a boolean value (which is stored in an ini file as 1 or 0), you'll get an int back.

Comment: That is an important limitation, yes. Unfortunately, it is impossible to find out the exact meaning then. (As is the case with a lot of possible values). Luckily it will not be a problem if you use it like `if getvalue(parser, "asection", "boollookslikeint"):`

Comment: Ultimately if the OP simply stores stuff in ini file format - without further meta data he won't be able to get the datatype back.

Comment: I found pyfig, but he can only read. https://bitbucket.org/alecwh/pyfig/overview                                                                                                                                                               player_age/float = 19

Comment: Pyfig doesn't automatically detect type either. It's actually impossible to do so: the value `1` could be a boolean, integer, float or string. `true` could be a boolean or a string.

Answer (score 0):

With `configobj` library, it becomes very simple.

```
import sys
import json
from configobj import ConfigObj

if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print "USAGE: pass ini file as argument"
    sys.exit(-1)

config = sys.argv[1]
config = ConfigObj(config)
```

Now you can use `config` as a dict to extract the desired configuration.

If you want to convert it to `json`, that's simple too.

```
config_json = json.dumps(config)
print config_json
```